# Div creating scroll bars

Tags: css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/yDx55/

The last div is supposed to be 100% for height but I want it to show only till the end of page, not beyond that which creates scroll bars. When the data inside the div goes beyond the end of div, then i would like it to expand but not if the content is very little.

```
|xx    |
|xx    |
|______|
```

That is how I want it to be when there is not a lot of content.

But when the content is a lot, I want it to be like the following:

```
|xx     |
|xx     |
|xx     |
|xx_____| << The point where if the content exceeds this, then a scroll bar comes up
|xx     |
|xx     |
|_______|
```

So basically, the scroll bar should come up if the content in the div crosses the page else, the scroll bars shouldn't come.

Please help

Comment: showing us your code always helps

Comment: do you want the scrollbars to appear for the page as a whole or just the bottom div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you always know the height of the first two elements (which in your example you do), you could position the last element absolutely at the foot of the page with `overflow: auto` to provide scroll bars when neccessery:

```
#last_div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 187px;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yDx55/2/**

Answer (score 1):

CSS: overflow:auto;

It will only show the scrollbar if the content is larger than the container. Use scroll to force it.

Comment: it doesn't, the scroll bars are still there.

Answer (score 0):

so make your Div have a min-height and set overflow to auto;

```
#div {

    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Tried it but the scroll bars are still there.

Comment: then there is more to your code that you are not saying. This would only show the scrollbars after 300px of height. set your height instead to the height that you want and leave out max-height.

Comment: The code is there and you can show me. I don't understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the CSS to only allow horizontal or vertical scrollbars to appear:

```
/*Vertical Scrollbar*/
#div {
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    overflow-x : hidden;
    overflow-y : auto;
}

/*Horizontal Scrollbar*/
#div {
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    overflow-x : auto;
    overflow-y : hidden;
}
```

You can also force the scrollbar to appear even if it isn't needed:

```
#div {
    width    : 100%;
    height   : 100%;
    overflow : scroll;
}
```

Here is an updated version of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yDx55/4/

Here is some excellent documentation for `overflow`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow

Comment: what a mess. You don't have to specify overflow-x and y separately if you have height and width on your div.

Comment: This is not what he wants. Setting the the height and width to 100% will either stretch it to the size of the screen or to the content. He wants the scrollbar to only appear at a certain height so setting it like this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @MichaelRader http://jsfiddle.net/vsnad/. This does not show a scrollbar if the content does not take up 100% of the viewport height and does show a scrollbar if the content gets long enough.

Comment: Exactly. The scroll bars appear according to the size of the window height. I thought he was looking for a set height to his div.

Comment: I have set the div to 100% height. There is no content in that div yet it still puts a scroll bar on the page and I have to scroll it down. I want the scroll bar to only appear when there the content inside the div extends beyond the page when there must be a scroll bar to see the rest of the page.

Comment: That is pretty good except the height part. I want the height to stretch all the way at the bottom but not show a scroll bar. I achieved this earlier but I can't get it to work. I think that the second div is causing this problem since the height of the second div is being added to the top margin of the last div and so that div starts after the second div with 100% height of the webpage and therefore to show the 100%, it shows a scroll bar. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: @user1079641 http://jsfiddle.net/yDx55/5/. How about that? Did you want the scrollbars to show up on the div itself or the regular page scrollbars?

Comment: I want the regular page scrollbars only if the div requires it.

Comment: Here it is:

I just want a regular page in which there is a div that has content. If the div expands to a point where you can't see  the content (For example, when it is too long and does not fit in your screen), I want the regular scrollbars to show up so they can take me down until the div ends. In this case, the div is just under two other divs. It should be the same thing though.